# Placing string in a specific location in a Dos scripts

Tags: dos

How do I insert a specific string to a specific place in a Dos script?

I searched it unsuccessfuly, so I'm sorry if I missed a similar topic before, and anyway: thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends a lot in what manner you mean. Normally parameters for the batch file would be used so

```
myscript.cmd parm1 parm2
```

you can use `%1` to get parm1 and `%2` to get parm2